# Как обращаться к массиву в strings.xml?

Tags: java, android

Есть массив в `strings.xml`:

```
<string-array name="arr_vol">
    <item>Минимальный</item>
    <item>Средний</item>
    <item>Максимальный</item>
</string-array>
```

Есть лист:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
```

Как присвоить листу `al` значения из массива `arr_vol`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавляете в **strings.xml** или в **arrays.xml** ваш `string-array`, и затем:

```
List<String> al = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arr_vol));
```